# my class instances disappear when they iterate through a for loop

Tags: python, class, for-loop, garbage-collection, selenium-chromedriver

So I am trying to open a series of web browsers at the same time. I have no issue doing this when I call individual class instances (correct me if it's instance of object). 
I'm trying to make my code more pretty and feed the args to the instances through a for loop. The browsers open fine but then they all disappear. I was told that this has to do with garbage collection but not sure how to get around it. Please help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from threading import Thread


class Dashboard(Thread):

    def __init__(self, position, url):
        super().__init__()       
        self.position = position
        self.url = url

    def run(self):

        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=256,160')
        #chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
        chrome_options.add_argument(self.position)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        self.driver.get(self.url)


pos = ['--window-position=100,100', '--window-position=1000,1000']
web = ['https://www.youtube.com', 'https://www.facebook.com']


for a, b in zip(pos, web):

    screen = Dashboard(a, b).start()
```

Comment: It is not disappearing. The run() function executes successfully and finishes it job. It gets the self.url and exit as expected.

Comment: This is not the case. The exit only happens when I try to integrate a for loop. And the webdriver exits when you call .quit(), otherwise, the browser stays open- except for when I use a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver gets out of scope which results into closing of browser. Add the driver to some global variable.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from threading import Thread

all_drivers = []


class Dashboard(Thread):

    def __init__(self, position, url):
        super().__init__()
        self.position = position
        self.url = url
        self.driver = None

    def run(self):
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=256,160')
        # chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
        chrome_options.add_argument(self.position)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        all_drivers.append(self.driver)


pos = ['--window-position=100,100', '--window-position=1000,1000']
web = ['https://www.youtube.com', 'https://www.facebook.com']

for a, b in zip(pos, web):
    screen = Dashboard(a, b).start()

# close the drivers once your purpose is solved
for driver in all_drivers:
    driver.quit()
```